# Windows and Linux Simultaneous EC2 Instances on AWS Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server, windows-server-2016, ec2-ami

I am running a Linux server with `10GB` of EBS Storage for personal projects on AWS's free tier. I also want to create another server on that same account, but I would rather not spend anything.

I tried to create a Windows server (which has a seperate compute-hours allowance), and gave it the remaining `20GB` of EBS Storage I had left (the Free Tier allowance is `30GB`). However, AWS wouldn't let me create a Windows server with less than `30GB` of space. I know that Windows shouldn't take that much space for sure.

Is there a way I can create a Windows instance with less than `20GB`?

Comment: Basically Windows server should need to have atleast that much space. Instead of it gives error later it prompts you early.
Look windows might take e.g. 15BG to 20GB, which you know keeps increasing by time due to any cache, temp and other stuff. You might need to install some kind of server or may be any development tools on same instances. So it should have atleast some reasonable minimum space so you do not get worry in the middle. Your application will also take some space, so nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Windows Server is that big (allowing for some spare storage space on the volume).

Please note that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is calculated on a **monthly basis**. So, you can actually run as many instances as you want, but turn them off when they are not being used. The first 750 hours of Amazon EC2 t2.micro for Linux *and* Windows is free. (So, you could run 2 Linux and 2 Windows, but turn them off for half the time).

The same thing applies to Amazon EBS storage:

> 30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage in any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic, plus 2 million I/Os (with EBS Magnetic) and 1 GB of snapshot storage*

So, you could use more than 30GB of storage, but not for the whole month.

The intention of the Free Tier is to allow people to try AWS and become familiar with how it works. It is *not* intended to provide free hosting for full-time production applications.

**Bottom line:** Just keep an eye on your *monthly totals*. For example, you can use twice the quantity for half the time and it will stay within the free tier.